# MySQL function using Rails/ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a problem in using Rails / ActiveRecord.

I want to insert record with MySQL function, for example `GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)')`.
Using ActiveRecord normally, these functions are quoted automatically. I want not to quote these values.

```
Model.create(geo: GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)'))
```

this ActiveRecord statement will generate following SQL

```
INSERT INTO `Model` (`geo`) VALUES ('GeomFromText(\'POINT(1 1)\')')
```

It may be easy to use raw SQL, but I want to use ActiveRecord because my Model set several callbacks include self table.

How can use MySQL function with ActiveRecord statement?

Comment: you want to store the value returned from the mysql function instead of the quoted text?

Comment: in this case, not need to filter mysql function. but the case in using mysql geometry type, statement of `GeomFromText` must contain. but ActiveRecord normally quote this and mysql don't recognize as function.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

#### Summary

You can't by design; this behavior is important for preventing SQL injection attacks. You would need to explicitly execute raw SQL in conjunction with ActiveRecord.

#### Details

As you saw, the SQL statement gets interpolated as a string by design, which doesn't do what you want (Rails ~> 4.0):

```
> Country.create(name: 'LOWER("CANADA")')
  => SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `Country` (`Name`) VALUES ('LOWER(\"CANADA\")')
```

Nor can you use the same tricks that would work for the `.where` method:

```
> Country.create(["name = LOWER(:country)", { country: 'CANADA' }])
  => ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

You would need to execute arbitrary SQL first to get the proper value, then make another SQL call via ActiveRecord to achieve your callback:

```
> Country.create( name: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(%q{ SELECT LOWER('CANADA') }).first[0] )
  =>     (0.3ms)  SELECT LOWER('CANADA')
  => SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `Country` (`Name`) VALUES ('canada')
```

That said, it's probably cleaner to re-implement the SQL function at the application layer instead of the DB layer (unless you've got a *really* complex SQL function).